# Requirements for including Enumerable

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I've been trying to design my read only Array data structure and I really like the idea of providing traversing options with Enumerable class, but I cannot find requirements of it. In some examples that I've looked, the C implementation looks for `#each` method, but it seems to me that it can't be enough.

Comment: FYI, `Enumerable` is a module, not a class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Pickaxe](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9) p. 474 and also from [the core documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html):

> The class [mixing in Enumerable] must provide a method `each`, which
>   yields successive members of the collection.  If `Enumerable#max`,
>   `min`, `sort`, or `sort_by` is used, the objects in the collection
>   must also implement a meaningful `<=>` operator, because these methods
>   rely on an ordering between members of a collection.

Comment: The same said in ruby documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html

Comment: @Alex, Thank you.  I added that link to the answer.